# How to proper cast in sqllite

Tags: sqlite

When i cast datetime in SQLLite, it truncates the string.
for example

```
select cast("2017-04-23 9:12:08 PM" as datetime) as dt
```

returns

```
2017
```

Comment: SQLite has no formal `datetime` type.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite's CAST can only cast to the defined storage classes and can therefore only be used to cast to

NONE (blob), TEXT, REAL, INTEGER or NUMERIC.

However the normal rules for determing column-affinity are applied to the type so by coding `CAST(value AS datetime)` you are effectively using `CAST(value AS NONE)` (i.e. a BLOB).

[CAST expressions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr)

Therefore you can't effectively use CAST. However you simply use the DateTime functions against an appropriate value (accepted formats) as per [Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) e.g. :-

```
SELECT datetime("2017-04-23 09:12:08") as dt;
```

results in

```
2017-04-23 09:12:08
```

or to show date manipulation

```
select date(dt), dt FROM (
    select datetime("2017-04-23 09:12:08") as dt
);
```

results in

```
2017-04-23
```

and

```
2017-04-23 09:12:08
```

However considering that your format isn't one of the accepted formats you could convert the value. This is more complex but it can be done. Here's an example that will perform the conversion (not substantially tested though) :-

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN (CAST(hour AS INTEGER) + CAST(adjustment AS INTEGER)) > 9  THEN 
            datepart||' '||CAST(CAST(hour AS INTEGER) + CAST(adjustment AS INTEGER) AS TEXT)||':'||mins_and_secs
        ELSE
            datepart||' 0'||CAST(CAST(hour AS INTEGER) + CAST(adjustment AS INTEGER) AS TEXT)||':'||mins_and_secs
    END AS converted
FROM (
    SELECT substr(ts,1,10) as datepart, 
        CASE WHEN instr(ts,"PM") THEN 12 ELSE 0 END AS adjustment,
        CASE WHEN length(ts) = 21 THEN substr(ts,12,1) ELSE substr(ts,12,2) END AS hour,
        CASE WHEN length(ts) = 21 THEN substr(ts,14,5) ELSE substr(ts,15,5) END AS mins_and_secs
    FROM (
        select("2017-04-23 9:12:08 PM") as ts
    )
);
```

This would result in **`2017-04-23 21:12:08`**.

Using `select("2017-04-23 9:12:08 AM")` results in **`2017-04-23 09:12:08`**

Using `select("2017-04-23 11:12:08 PM")` results in **`2017-04-23 23:12:08`**

Using `select("2017-04-23 11:12:08 AM")` results in **`2017-04-23 11:12:08`**

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could come up with is:

```
select date(datetime(strftime('%s','2017-04-23 09:12:08'), 'unixepoch'))
```

Result:

```
2017-04-23
```

The dateformat you have is not recognised by SQLite:

```
"2017-04-23 9:12:08 PM"
```

It does not conform to the Time string formats recognised:

> A time string can be in any of the following formats:
>
> ```
> YYYY-MM-DD
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
> HH:MM
> HH:MM:SS
> HH:MM:SS.SSS
> now
> DDDDDDDDDD
> ```

[Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)